# Magento 2 Where is Product attribute Website_id stored in DB?

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

In Magento 2, when editing a product, we can choose which website this product belongs to. But I can't find where is this information stored in the database.

I have checked `eav_attribute`, and I found out that the attribute `website_id` has **attribute_id** 1

I tried to look at the table *catalog_product_entity_int*, but I can't find any attribute_id = 1. So where is the relation for website_id and products stored in the DB?

---

EDIT,

Oh, that website_id I found in table `eav_attribute` is actually for the customers. So where is the **website attribute** for products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can find the relation betweenn products and website in this table "catalog_product_website"

Tell me if it works .

Good Luck !!!

Comment: Thanks, I found it. How come I didn't know that :)